# How to use listagg in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, oracle11g

I am trying to use listagg function to generate a list of users.

Consider the following table

```
 ROLE_ID    ENAME
---------- ----------
       4    CLARK
       4    KING
       4    MILLER
       7    ADAMS
       9    FORD
       9    JONES
```

On using the following query in the SQL Developer

```
SELECT ROLE_ID,
       LISTAGG(ENAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENAME) AS EMPLOYEES 
FROM USERS 
GROUP BY ROLE_ID;
```

will result in the following in the console output

```
ROLE_ID EMPLOYEES
-----------------------------
4        CLARK,KING,MILLER
7        ADAMS
9        FORD, JONES
```

My goal is try doing this in hibernate but I am not sure how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Stanley, have u got any solution to register listagg method in hibernate dialect . I am also struggling with same issue

Answer (score 7):

For anyone having problems using listagg as part of a formula, registering the "within" keyword with Hibernate solved the problem for me. (Using Hibernate 5.0.7.)

```
public class CustomOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public CustomOracleDialect() {
        super();

        registerKeyword("within");
    }
}
```

Prior to this, Hibernate would break the query by attempting to prefix the "within" keyword with the outer table's alias. Once the keyword was registered the following works:

```
@Formula("(select (listagg(l.serial_number, ', ') within group(order by d.serial_number))\n"
        + "from order_lines l\n"
        + "where l.order_id = id\n"
        + "group by l.order_id)")
private String serialNumbers;
```

Note that if you try to assign an alias to the listagg expression it still breaks the query, as Hibernate tries to prepend it with the table's alias as well. This of course is not an issue with formula queries, but if using listagg as part of a named query you may need to omit the alias and reference the column by position within the result set.

Comment: For spring project, add "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" in application.properties.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

We found a good solution.

```
@Formula("(select (listagg(l.serial_number, ', ') \00within group(order by d.serial_number))\n"
    + "from order_lines l\n"
    + "where l.order_id = id\n"
    + "group by l.order_id)")
private String serialNumbers;
```

Just append the \00 before WITHIN keyword.
And you don't need to extends anything.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot struggle i found this solution. I think it will help you all.You can register `LISTAGG` function like below

```
registerFunction("LISTAGG", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING,"LISTAGG(?1,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ?1)"));
```

and you can use `LISTAGG(<columnname>)` in your hibernate query

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't understand sql function be default. Try registering in hibernateDialect.

```
registerFunction("listAgg", new StandardSQLFunction("listAgg", Hibernate.STRING));
```

Comment: @Ravi- Thanks for responding. Tried this didn't really work getting errors by hibernate.ast

Comment: @Stanley : You should override dialect : public class CustomDialect  extends Oracle10gDialect{
 public MRADialect() {
  CustomDialect("listagg", new StandardSQLFunction("listagg"));

 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Registering of listagg method is not working in hibernate dialect .              Try with registering wm_concat method , it worked for me ..

Find below code ..

```
public class ServiceAppOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
     public ServiceAppOracle10gDialect() {
            super();
            //registerFunction("LISTAGG", new StandardSQLFunction("LISTAGG", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
            registerFunction("wm_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("wm_concat", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        }
}
```

And make sure that u have changed your hibernate.dialect property ..

```
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.apple.sc.analytics.utils.ServiceAppOracle10gDialect</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use listagg in hibernate query

1. First register listagg function in Hibernate Dialect by extending Oracle10gDialect(in case you are using Oracle) or MySQLDialect(for MySQL)

`public class CustomOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
     public CustomOracle10gDialect() {
         super();
         registerFunction("LISTAGG", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING,"LISTAGG(?1,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ?1)"));
    }
}`

2. Update your config file to use custom dialect.
   spring.jpa.database-platform=com.abc.CustomOracle10gDialect
   or 
   com.abc.CustomOracle10gDialect
3. Use LISTAGG()
   Example -
   select c.id, listagg(firstName) from Contacts c where  GROUP BY c.id